# Как заставить регулярку искать пересекающиеся совпадения?

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка: `s = "!(B)(A))"`
Есть паттерн: `pat = r"[!+*abc()][ABTM]??[!+*abc()]"`
Мне нужно из `s` вытащить **все** вхождения паттерна в эту строку, т.е. `!(`, `(B)`, `)(`, `(A)`, `))`.

```py
import re


s = "!(B)(A))"
pat = r"[!+*abc()][ABTM]??[!+*abc()]"

matches = re.findall(pat, s)
print(matches) 
# Вывод ['!(', ')(', '))']
# Нужно ['!(', '(B)', ')(', '(A)', '))']
```

Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/ex0YKA

```
import re

s = "!(B)"
pat = r"(?=([!+*abc()][ABTM]??[!+*abc()]))"

matches = re.findall(pat, s)
print(matches)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сам пробовал проверить positive lookahead (`(?=...)`) на regex101, но там я, почему-то, не получил нужного мне результата https://regex101.com/r/CruDBc/3.